# why the value duplicated in all the list elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the following structure:

```
l = [[[],0]] * 5
```

each node in the list contains another list:

- first element in the inner list contains another list
- second element in the inner list contains wight

I'm trying to add value to the inner list:

```
index = 0
l[index][0].append('s')
```

but it add the values `'s'` to all list (`l`) values:

```
l = [[['s'],0], [['s'],0], [['s'],0], [['s'],0], [['s'],0]]
```

- why the value 's' duplicates to all the list element ?
- how can I add the value 's' only to the first inner list
  (i.e `l = [[['s'],0], [[],0], [[],0], [[],0], [[],0]]`)

Python `3.6.8`

Comment: Because `l[0] is l[1]`. All the list you've created are shallow copies of the same list. It's Python's feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `* 5` part of your statement, as it generates 5 aliases of the same list object instead of 5 different list instances. You can imagine your statement written equivalently as follows:

```
a = [[],0]
l = [a,a,a,a,a]
```

This follows the evaluation order of your statement and makes it more evident that the list `l` is in fact a list of 5 aliases.

Replacing the definition of `l` with a comprehension fixes the issue:

```
l = [[[],0] for _ in range(5)]
```

In the comprehension, the loop over `range` ensures that at each position a new instance is created (check, for instance, `l[0] is not l[1]`), so that the append can work as you expect it to:

```
l[0][0].append(1)
print(l)
```

prints

```
[[[1], 0], [[], 0], [[], 0], [[], 0], [[], 0]]
```